# How to clear shared preferences from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

How i can clear shared preferences from fragment? Thank you

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent logout = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(logout);
        Log.d(TAG, sharedPreferences.getString("username", ""));
        Log.d(TAG, sharedPreferences.getString("password", ""));
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_logout, container, false);
    }
```

That my fragment

Comment: What do you want to reach?

Comment: i want to get shared preferences from activity and then clear from fragment, is it posible?

Comment: what is the problem with current code?

Comment: This should work, but if you want, you can user editor.remove("key-value*").commit();

Comment: i think, i can't clear shared preferences.

Comment: @DennyKurniawan, check out the answer it works

Comment: @DennyKurniawan your program is correct...it clears the data so Log.d not showing the values....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_logout, container, false);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    Intent logout = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(logout);
    Log.d(TAG, sharedPreferences.getString("username", ""));
    Log.d(TAG, sharedPreferences.getString("password", ""));
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

Comment: still cant, thanks for answer. i think something wrong in my pogram, because log.d is not displayed.

Comment: @DennyKurniawan if your log.d is not displaying it means your key value pair removed from sharedprefrence .

Comment: @Denny if u can't see ur log means ur preference values are cleared, simple.

Comment: @Denny consider accepting answer if helped and for intent it is an event which will occur only when a command is applied means set the intent method inside a button click.

Comment: @W4R10CK Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

you can directly use preference name and clear it from anywhere.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
preferences.edit().remove("shared_pref_key").commit();
```

or

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences .edit().clear().commit();
```